# Testcafe: Expectation on the length of a textarea

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I put a `maxLength` on a `textarea`, and I would like to assert that if I type more characters than the `maxLength`, the extra characters are truncated.  I couldn't figure out how to do this in testcafe in an easy way.  This did not work:

```
.expect(Selector('textarea#announcementText').value.length)
.eql(600)
```

But, `value` does not have a `length` on it.  There is not a `length` function in the assert API either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Selector().value](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/domnodestate.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes) field returns an asynchronous property. You can get its value and then check its length in the assertion:

```
const textAreaValue = await Selector('textarea#announcementText').value;

await t
    .expect(textAreaValue.length)
    .eql(600);
```

You can also check it by using the `match` assertion:

```
await t
    .expect(Selector('textarea#announcementText').value)
    .match(/^.{0,600}$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that seems indirect.  Here's how it works:

```
const getLengthOfAnnouncementText = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('textarea#announcementText').value.length);
...
.expect(getLengthOfAnnouncementText())
.eql(600)
```

This works the way I want, but I don't like how specific this function is.  Is there an easier way to do this?